# How can I recover from an erronous git push --force origin main

Tags: git, github

How can I recover from an git push --force origin main

I can't find all commit after I used
git push --force origin main, only last one so  can I undo my commits

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the reflog to reconstruct the state of the branch as you want it on your machine, and force push again.

Comment: so How to recover from a git push -force